# How to make the main thread wait for the internal threads after starting them?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

How to make the main thread wait for the internal threads after starting them in python?

I use `join` for this but it doesn't work correctly, I think it occurred because the internal threads call `time.sleep()`. 
Any Idea?

Here is the block box of the code:

```
def execution(start,end):
    for i in range (start,end):
        main ()
    return

def waitForThread(delay,my_threads):
    time.sleep (delay)
    for t in my_threads:
        t.join ()
        if t in my_threads:
            my_threads.remove (t)
    return

def task(user,sleep): # it has multiple time.sleep()
    #do some actions
    time.sleep()
    #do some actions
    time.sleep()
    return  

def main():
    threads=[]
    for user in accounts:
        t = Thread (target=task,args=(sleep-time,user))
        t.start ()
        threads.append (t)
    waitForThread (130,threads)

    ## I want the code stop here and when the execution of threads finished continue 

    ## doing other staff here 

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    execution(1,30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
def waitForThread(delay,my_threads):
    time.sleep (delay)
    for t in my_threads:
        t.join ()
        if t in my_threads:
            my_threads.remove (t)
    return
```

looks fishy. Especially the lines

```
        if t in my_threads:
            my_threads.remove (t)
```

These lines will remove elements from `my_threads` within the `for`loop and therefore you will not wait for all threads to finish.

If you remove these lines, the code will wait for the threads to join properly. Then, if you feel you need to remove the threads, you can do that (e.g. using `del`) when `waitForThread` return.

The take-home lesson is to not modify the list of elements - at least not by adding or removing elements -  that you are looping over within a `for` loop. That often has strange effects.

Comment: I seriously doubt that just removing those lines will make the code work based just on the unrunnable code in the OP's answer.

Comment: @martineau OK, I modified my answer to address the specific problem that was asked about in the OP.